# The right way to put querystring-style information in the location bar in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net 4.0 application. One of the site does is allow users to search for stuff in the database. The page that is done on looks like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server" DefaultButton="lnkSearch" cssclass="searchbar box">
    <span id="searchFor"><strong>Search for</strong></span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="lnkSearch_Click"></asp:LinkButton>              
</asp:Panel>
```

`lnkSearch_Click` performs the query on the database, then binds the results to a `asp:Repeater`.

This all works, but there is a problem: The URL is not changed for the user, and so there is no way for the user to save a query for later, or to link to to their friends.

I could solve this by doing something a bit like:

```
<script>
    function doSearch() { location.href='~/defaultpro.aspx?search='+escape($('txtSearch').value);
</script>
<a ID="lnkSearch" href="javascript:void(0);" Text="Search" onclick="doSearch();" />
```

But this feels like going out of my way to avoid using the tools asp.net provides. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: BTW default button of panel doesn't work in firefox for linkbutton control

Comment: I noticed. webforms is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of doing it is to have a form with method set to get:

```
<form method="get">
```

But ASP.NET requires the one huge form that wraps all the controls, so **its not an option** for you.

Other way you can implement this, is to create an event handler for click event of your Search button:

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl + "?search=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtSearch.Text));
}
```

And bind all the data in the `PageLoad` event

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4.0 why are you not using URL Routing?
I wrote this [article](http://chadcarter30101.blogspot.com/2011/07/url-routing-in-aspnet-40-simple-example.html) explaining how to use the new feature.

So you would have a click event that performs your search and then at the end of the search (logic code) you can keep their search in the URL by using URL Routing.
Another method you could use is Sessions.  I would not suggest cookies as they are on the client and prone to manipulation.  One last option you could use is Context.
If you are going from one page directly to the next you could use page history.